# Encode Unicode characters in dict to send as data in a POST request

Tags: python, post, python-requests

If you check this page (http://buses.com/EN/cr/index.php) and enter in the `From` section `Golfito` and the `To` section `Cañon del Guarco` (date and other sections are not really important) you will be redirected to a page with a schedule. 
I was playing around with requests in python and wanted to do it via code. After checking what sort of data was sent along the POST request I created a dict with the following keys and values

```
d = {'fromClass': 'Golfito',
'toClass': 'Cañon del Guarco',
'viaClass': '',
'jDate': '01/12/2020',
'jTime': '21:20',
'addtime': '0',
'lang': 'en',
'b2': 'Search connection'}
```

and I called the post function of the requests lib:

```
r = requests.post('http://horariodebuses.com/EN/cr/index.php', data=d)
```

and it will basically fail, claiming that their database doesnt have any `Cañon del Guarco` even though I was able to do so via their website. (You can see that by yourself if you save `r` as an html file)
However if you change the To section to another city that doesnt have any unicode (like `Liberia` for example, it will work. Via the code (by changing toClass) and via the website as well. It will basically fail for cities with unicode character via the code.

Am I not encoding my dict properly ?

edit: 
I tried to encode all my values with utf-8 by doing the following:

```
data = {k: str(v).encode("utf-8") for k,v in d.items()}
```

edit2:
I was able to see the form data using the Google dev console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page doesn't use `UTF-8` but `ISO-8859-1` or something similar because it converts `ñ` to `%F1` and `ISO-8859-1` converts to `\xf1` but it also gives results.

```
import requests
import webbrowser

d = {
    'fromClass': 'Golfito',
    'toClass': 'Cañon del Guarco',
    'viaClass': '',
    'jDate': '01/12/2020',
    'jTime': '21:20',
    'addtime': '0',
    'lang': 'en',
    'b2': 'Search connection'
}

d = {k: str(v).encode("ISO-8859-1") for k,v in d.items()}
r = requests.post('http://horariodebuses.com/EN/cr/index.php', data=d)
print(r.encoding)  # ISO-8859-1
print(r.request.body)

with open('output.html', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
webbrowser.open('output.html')
```

---

**EDIT:** `urllib.parse.urlencode()` and header `Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` sends `%F1` for `ñ` and `+` for `spaces` and it gives results

```
import requests
import urllib.parse
import webbrowser

d = {
    'fromClass': 'Golfito',
    'toClass': 'Cañon del Guarco',
    'viaClass': '',
    'jDate': '01/12/2020',
    'jTime': '21:34',
    'addtime': '0',
    'lang': 'en',
    'b2': 'Search connection'
}

d = urllib.parse.urlencode(d, encoding='ISO-8859-1')
h = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
#print(d)

r = requests.post('http://horariodebuses.com/EN/cr/index.php', data=d, headers=h)

#print(r.encoding)
#print(r.request.body)
#print(r.request.headers)

with open('output.html', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
webbrowser.open('output.html')
```